# How can I get my US passport from abroad?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, philippines, minors

I'm 17 and I am applying for a US passport in the Philippines. Do I use the DS-11 form? Although I'm a US citizen, my guardian doesn't have legal custody and my mother can't be located. So far, I haven't been able to get a US passport because I am only 17 and am not in the US.

How and where can I apply and how long does the process take?

My father is trying to get a passport for me from within the US; will he be able to do this?

Comment: Were you born in the US, or were you born abroad? If abroad, then do you have a Consular Report of Birth Abroad (CRBA)?

Comment: "my guardian doesn't have legal custody and my mother can't be located" Well, who has legal custody?

Comment: "So far, I haven't been able to get a US passport because I am only 17 and am not in the US." What exactly has been stopping you from getting a US passport? Are you missing proof of US citizenship? or missing parental consent? Are the statements on the [passports for 16- and 17-year-olds](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/16-17.html) page, that they only need either an ID or one parent's awareness, not true when applying abroad?

Comment: Ive been living withing my mothers friend before she left i was born in the US. By legal custody i meant that my guardian doesnt have real paperwork that actually says hes my guardian. Will my father in the US be able to get a passport for me?

Comment: If my father was able to get a passport how would he get it without me to represent myself?

Comment: Since i am 17 how come i cant just apply for my passport without my parents. The US embassy is very far from where i am and a bus ticket costs a lot id like to be informed as much as possible before i go to the embassy

Comment: @user72433: "Will my father in the US be able to get a passport for me?" No. You must be present to apply for your passport.

Comment: @user72433: "Since i am 17 how come i cant just apply for my passport without my parents." Who's telling you you can't? According to the Department of State page, it seems like if you have an ID or one parent's sent that should be enough.

Comment: What kind of ID? I dont have a license and the only thing close to an ID is my school ID im sorry did u mean parents consent?

Answer (score 3):

The best source for instructions on what you need to do comes from the U.S. Embassy in the Philippines. Follow the directions on the [Apply for an Adult Passport](https://ph.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/apply-for-an-adult-passport/) page.

You will probably need a considerable amount of documentation in order to apply for your first passport. The Passport Checklist details what you will need.

It may be possible for your father to submit the application on your behalf, but he will need at least a signed statement from you authorizing him to do so, plus the same stack of documentation that you would need to apply yourself.

Comment: I have a couple questions in the comment section could u plz answer

Comment: If my dad was able to apply would i still need to apply here also?

Comment: You only need to submit an application for a passport once. The government will not issue two passports for the same person, and submitting two applications won't help. To actually apply, you will submit a bunch of information online, get all your documentation together (they provide detailed checklists for this), submit your documentation to them, and make an appointment. Then, once you have the appointment date and time (and they have done a preliminary check of your documentation), you will book a bus ticket, show up for your interview, and then go home and wait.

Comment: I filled out a form online and sent it to my dad for him to present. Would they accept that? I put in everything i needed to put in birthcertificate,sss, an ID and it says my dad has to present it to a travel agency other than my signature would they accept the DS-11 and allow me to obtain a passport?

Comment: Wait, slow down. What does the travel agency have anything to do with it?

Comment: I havent been to any travel agency yet because spending money to get to the nearest agency is alot (bus fare and taxi fares) id rather know as much as possible b4 i really have to go and apply if i can